Calculating generation time in "An Illustrated guide to theoretical ecology"
I am new to this site and I am trying to learn theoretical ecology with the book "An illustrated guide to theoretical ecology". In chapter 4, they give the following exercice : "Find the discrete growth rate ($\lambda$), the $R_0$ and the generation time, $T$, for a life history where reproductive maturity occurs at 1 year, survival of age 0 is $S_0 = 0.6/year$ and each adult age has survivorship $S = 0.8/year$ and fecundity $b= 2$.
Earlier in the book, they define $R_0$ and $T$ as $$R_0 = \sum_{x=0}^\max l_xb_x$$ and $$T = \frac{\sum_{x=0}^\max l_xb_xx}{\sum_{x=0}^\max l_xb_x} =\frac{\sum_{x=0}^\max l_xb_xx}{R_0}$$where $l_x = \prod_{i=1}^{x-1} S_x$ (or survival until age $x$) and $b_x$ corresponds to fecundity of age $x$.
I can easily compute $R_0$ with the following algebra, which gives the correct answer according to the book : $$R_0 =l_0b_0+l_1b_1+l_2b_2+l_3b_3\dots$$
$$=1*0+S_0b+S_0Sb+S_0S^2+\dotsb$$
$$=S_0b*(1+S+S^2+S^3+\dots)$$
$$=S_0b*(\sum_{x=0}^\infty S^x) = \frac{S_0*b}{1-S} = \frac{2*0.6}{1-0.8} = 6$$
However, when I try to compute the generation time, I cannot get the right answer :
$$T = \frac{l_0b_0*0 + l_1b_1*1 +l_2b_2*2 + l_3b_3 *3 + \dots}{R_0}$$
$$=\frac{0+S_0b*1+S_0Sb*2+S_0S^2b*3 +\dots}{R_0}$$
$$=\frac{S_0b*(1+S*2 +S^2*3 + \dots)}{R_0}$$
$$=\frac{S_0b*(\sum_{x=0}^\infty S^x(x+1))}{R_0} = \frac{1}{R_0}*\frac{S_0b}{(1-S)^2} = \frac{1}{6}*\frac{0.6*2}{(1-0.8)^2} = 5$$
In the book, they find $T$ by finding $\lambda$ first $$\lambda = S + S_0b = 0.8 +0.6*2 = 2$$ and using this result to find $T$ :
$$T = \frac{\ln(R_0)}{\ln(\lambda)} = \frac{\ln(6)}{\ln(2)} = 2.58$$
I understand the way they do it in the book, but I don't understand what is wrong with my reasoning. Both ways of doing it should lead to the same result. Is there something that I missed ?
Thank you !

There are three kinds of generation time $T$ and you've calculated two different kinds. The first is time for the population to grow by a factor of its net reproductive rate. This is what the book calculated with $\frac{\ln R_0}{\ln \lambda}$. This definition is nice mathematically but doesn't really match our intuition of say, generations of our family.
For that we have two other measures. You've correctly calculated the expected age of reproduction. You can see this because the numerator is the sum of the ages of reproduction and the denominator is the average number of offspring. This makes sense because you can think of generations as being leaps of this size.
There is also a third way which is the average age difference between parents and offspring. This perhaps best models what we think of when we say a generation in the child, parent, grandparent sense of the word. Humans are an interesting case to better understand the differences between the three measures.

Thank you for your answer ! There is still something I find hard to understand though. Even if there are many ways to calculate or to conceptualize the same quantity, all these methods should approximately lead to the same result. Why are the results so different here ? If all these formulas refer to different quantities, shouldn't they have different names ?

@jiraf They are not all different measures of the same thing, rather they're three different measures that each describe different properties of the population. It would be unusual for them all to be the same. It's like how mean, median and mode are all measures of central tendency but the differences between them help us better understand how the data is distributed.

Thank you a lot !
